# Intellij - Find path to src directory

Tags: intellij-idea

I am creating an IntelliJ plugin and I am using JavaParser for one of my features. My plugin will allow users to click a gutter icon next to a method and automatically navigate to the tests associated with that method.

To achieve this, temporerily I have used the line:

`typeSolver.add(new JavaParserTypeSolver(new File("/home/webby/IdeaProjects/project00/src/")));`

My problem is that I need to pass the source folder of the given module into this type solver. Is there any way I can find the source folder programmatically? Perhaps from an actionEvent?

I have tried things along the lines of the following:

`actionEvent.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT).getBasePath()`

This gives me: '/home/webby/IdeaProjects/project00/' but I'm struggling to see how I can get the source folder? I feel there should be a fairly straight forward way of doing this using IntelliJ's SDK but I have not found anything in the documentation or anywhere else online.

Any and all solutions welcome!

Many Thanks,
James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ModuleRootManager.getInstance(module).getSourceRoots()
```

to access sources roots of a module. Refer to [IntelliJ SDK Docs](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/project_model/module.html) for details.

BTW IntelliJ IDEA provides special [API](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/architectural_overview/psi_elements.html) to syntax trees of Java files, it works more efficiently and better integrates with other IDE features than external JavaParsers.

And it's better to ask questions about IntelliJ IDEA API on [a special forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development).